# In Android app, can I replace the "me" of facebook's graph API in a new Request with my id?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried many different ways and looked at many answers on stackoverflow, nothing helped.
It's fairly straightforward. I am making a new request to get the 3 first pictures from the profile album of facebook.

```
new Request(session, "me", getRequestParameters() , null, 
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    buildSelectedProfile(response);
                }  
            }
            ).executeAsync();


private Bundle getRequestParameters() {
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle(1);
    parameters.putString("fields", "albums{type,photos.limit(3)}");
    return parameters;
}
```

and that worked fine but as soon as I replace "me" with my id the app crashes with the following error

> 01-30 03:13:11.249: E/AndroidRuntime(3871): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-30 03:13:11.249: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 01-30 03:13:11.249:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3871):   at
>   test.app.facebookconnect.UpdateProfile.buildSelectedProfile(UpdateProfile.java:221)
>   01-30 03:13:11.249: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):   at
>   test.app.facebookconnect.UpdateProfile.access$3(UpdateProfile.java:218)
>   01-30 03:13:11.249: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):   at
>   test.app.facebookconnect.UpdateProfile$5.onCompleted(UpdateProfile.java:165)
>   01-30 03:13:11.249: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):   at
>   com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1666) 01-30 03:13:11.249:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3871):   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 01-30
>   03:13:11.249: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 01-30
>   03:13:11.249: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 01-30 03:13:11.249:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3871):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039) 01-30
>   03:13:11.249: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-30
>   03:13:11.249: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 01-30 03:13:11.249:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3871):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   01-30 03:13:11.249: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 01-30
>   03:13:11.249: E/AndroidRuntime(3871):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

When I use the Graph API explorer with the following GET

> /v2.2/me?fields=albums{type,photos.limit(3)}

or

> /v2.2/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?fields=albums{type,photos.limit(3)}, they both
>   give me

the same Json result.
*note that XXXXXXXXXXXXXX represents a user id

Can anyone help? I looked at the Facebook documentation but all their examples use "me" and with the app I am making I need to gather id from different people and display them in the app.

Thank you

Comment: What id? And where did you get the id from?

Comment: I can get my id from Graph API explorer Tool "https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/" by entering this in the field "me?fields=id" or I could do it in the code like this 'code ' public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                  if (user != null) {
                      // Display the parsed user info
                   String user_id = user.getId();
                   Log.d("GraphUser", "User ID " + user_id);
                   userInfoTextView.setText(buildUserInfoDisplay(user));
                  }
              }

Comment: Which access token are you using to get it? You are sure that you are using an access token from the same app that you are later doing the requests? What is the id?

Comment: Yes its the same access token that I am using! I think ??, I am using the same session in private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) { my code }.

Comment: oops sorry missed that part the id is 10155136664605713

Comment: And you are sure you used the right app in Graph Explorer? Have the user id  10155136664605713 granted permission to your app to access photos?

If you do a /me request and check for the id that is returned. Is that the same as 10155136664605713?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, It was a simple syntax issue. all that had to be done if I wanted to replace "me" is add my user-id with a Forward slash before it "/" 
like this:

```
new Request(session, "/10155150840690713", getRequestParameters() , null, new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    buildSelectedProfile(response);
                    }
                }
            ).executeAsync();
```

Cant believe I wasted so much time on this.
Thanks WizKid for trying to help me out, Next time I will try to be clearer with my questions!